# stripping white space in dictionary key

Tags: python-3.x, strip

I am very new to Python.

This is some of the data on a rugby match.

```
my_stats =     [{'_id': 'GLEvHIL2020031419A', 
    'stats': 
    {'data': 
    [{'area': 'D1', 'key': 'Lineouts', 'possession': 'for', 'second': 33, 'endSecond': 45, 'time': '2020-03-14T12:00:45', 'Lineout Formations': '5 Man', 'Lineout Area Of Throw': 'Front', 'Lineout Contested': 'Contested', 'Lineout Presentation': 'Scrappy', 'Lineout Errors': 'Lost', 'Maul Meters': '5'}]}}]
```

So this leaves us with my_stats. of which the data at the top is a list with two dictionaries. `_id` and `stats`

`stats` is the key to another dictionary of which the key is `data` but the value of `data` is a list. In this list, each entry into the database is a dictionary. One of which I have pasted here to make it easier.

My issue is that I need to strip  all keys in the dictionaries from their white space in order for me to reference them but the dictionary is in a list.

Here is an example of a definition that I created.

It works fine if I remove `(and (i[('Lineout Contested')])== 'Contested'))`.

it also works fine if I replace it with another key that is one word.

I am thinking that I will have to loop through all the data and strip the white space.

```
 def Our_Lineouts_Won():
        keys = []
        Lineouts = (0)
        for l in my_stats:
            t=(l['stats']['data'])
            print(l['_id'])
        
            for i in t:
           
                if ((i['key']) == 'Lineouts' and (i['possession'])== 'for' and (i[('Lineout Contested')])== 
                'Contested'):
                
                    Lineouts = Lineouts + 1  
            print(Lineouts)   
            Lineouts = (0) 
        
    
        
    Our_Lineouts_Won()
```

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your problem isn't whitespace. Whitespace in keys works fine. Your problem is the key name is `'**Lineout Contested**'` and not `'Lineout Contested'`.

Comment: Thank you @Axe319 but the double ** appeared when I highlighted the word in stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you edit it out if it's not included in the `dict`? Removing the asterisks from your `dict` and adding a few missing closing curly braces and a bracket to it works for me.

Comment: I have edited the data.

Comment: You're still missing `}}]` at the end of it. Does it not work after you add that?

Comment: @Axe319 Thank you for your persistence.. I have tried to add the brackets. I also cut much of the other data out to make it less overwhelming. I also tried to layout my problem a bit better.

Comment: Just so I'm certain, the reason you think you need to trim the whitespace is because you think the problem with this part `(and (i[('Lineout Contested')])== 'Contested'))` is caused by the whitespace in `'Lineout Contested'`?

Comment: The reason I ask is because if I copy/paste your example `dict` and the associated code, it runs.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/ylXc_YPR7 Here is an example.

Comment: I can not see your example, but this is the error it gives me: 
 line 126, in Our_Lineouts_Won
    if ((i['key']) == 'Lineouts' and (i['possession'])== 'for' and (i['Lineout Contested'])== 'Contested' ):

KeyError: 'Lineout Contested'

Comment: When I ran the code in jupyter now, it worked to... I will look for the fault further. Thank you for your help

Comment: morning @Axe319, I found the issue. One of the lineouts in the match did not have the 'Lineouts Contested' data in the dictionary. I think I now need to find a way to .get() a 0 value in there. Have a good day.

Comment: You could add a `lineout = i.get('Lineout Contested', None)` on the line before and then check if `lineout is None` in your condition. That's typically what I do for `dict` keys that may or may not be present.

Comment: I managed to figure out what was wrong... not al the lineouts had 'Lineout Contested' in the dictionary. I managed to get around it with: